# Is it possible to switch the recording tab in chrome that is being recorded using chrome.tabCaptire API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs, permissions, manifest

I am recording my chrome tab using [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) API, now while I switch the tab, the recording must be continued in the current tab and must be stopped in the old tab. While I try to stop the stream in the previous tab and start tried to get the stream of the currently active tab, I ran into the following exception

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission).

P.S : I have added activeTab attribute in the permission section of my manifest.json

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible: for every tab your extension must be invoked. This has nothing to do with `activeTab` permission - the error just mentions it as the [principle of invocation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab) is the same.

When a user switches away from the tab that it granted permission to record, the assumption is that you don't get rights for another tab implicitly. Each call to `chrome.tabCapture.capture` only grants it for a specific tab.

This is a security feature, and you need to ask the user to interact with your extension again.

You may consider switching to `chrome.desktopCapture` to capture the whole of Chrome window to allow what you ask for - but it will be a very different user experience.